# ECS Fargate Node.js child_process NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated

Tags: node.js, child-process, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I'm trying to use ECS to automate infrastructure and application deployments. The deployment logic is reasonably complex and will likely become more complex over time so I opted to use Node.js to handle the orchestration. Certain steps in the deployment require me to execute another binary in the container, specifically `terraform`. The problem is the child process that is created by Node.js doesn't appear to have the same permissions as the Node.js process.

**Some details**

- The ECS container is being launched by Fargate.
- The Task Definition has a Task Role which give it permission to do all of the things it needs including all the operations that are executed by terraform.
- I've tested that the permissions are sufficient by creating a user with identical permissions and was able to successfully execute the deployment locally.
- I know that the permissions are being granted to the Node.js process because it is able to perform operations such as s3:GetObject on a private bucket to which it is granted access by the Task Role
- When `terraform` attempts to call an AWS api it yields the following error "NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated."
- I have tried executing the terraform command by using child_process.spawn as well as child_process.exec. Both give the same error.

After trouble shooting this for a while, I'm fairly confident that the issue has to do with the Task Role not being handed off to the child process. Is it possible to do this hand off? and if so, how?

In case it helps, here is a modified terraform script to illustrate by ECS setup. The main difference is the Task Role has more permissions in one I'm using.

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "deploy" {
  family = "deploy-task"
  container_definitions = <<EOF
[
  {
    "name": "deploy",
    "image": "<ecr image uri>:latest",
    "essential": true,
    "memoryReservation": 128,
    "logConfiguration": {
      "logDriver": "awslogs",
      "options": {
        "awslogs-group": "/ecs/deploy-task",
        "awslogs-region": "us-east-1",
        "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
      }
    }
  }
]
EOF
  task_role_arn = "${aws_iam_role.task.arn}"
  execution_role_arn = "${aws_iam_role.execution.arn}"
  network_mode = "awsvpc"
  cpu = 256
  memory = 512
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
}

resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "deploy" {
  name = "deploy-cluster"
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "task" {
  name = "ecs-deploy-task"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "s3-policy" {
  name = "s3-policy"
  role = "${aws_iam_role.task.id}"

  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource": "<private s3 bucket>/*"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "execution" {
  name = "ecs-deploy-execution"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "execution" {
  role = "${aws_iam_role.execution.id}"
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy"
}
```

Comment: Where are you running this Terraform that deploys ECS from? From local, from ECS, from Lambda, from a certain CI/CD pipeline tool?